# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu with Software Updater

Tags: upgrade

SOFTWARE UPDATER

"The software on this computer is up to date.
However, Ubuntu 21.10  is now available (you have 20.04)."

"SETTINGS: Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version."

I hit Upgrade.

(The window closes and nothing happens.  I have done this several times.)

How to fix this? I could also upgrade with Terminal, but I'm afraid I would need commands that I could cut and paste, because I'm pretty ignorant.

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. There is no upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.10 and it is a really bad idea anyway.

Comment: I would not do this release-upgrade as 21.10 will be EOL soon. Wait till you can upgrade to 22.04 LTS ( 22.04.1 can be expected August 4 2022 ) and keep using 20.04 LTS for now. Support for 21.10 ends July 14 2022. See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10 is a *supported* upgrade path; however I'd still not use it, as the [Ubuntu 21.10 release will soon be EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) so you'll be upgrading to 21.10, then need to *release-upgrade* again to 22.04 LTS in a week or two.

Your *direct upgrade* path to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS will open **after** the release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS which is scheduled to occur on 4-August-2022. See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/ which states

> Users of Ubuntu 21.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 22.04. Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August

I'd recommend staying on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS until that direct-upgrade path is offered to you. Yes you can *release-upgrade* to it now (it's documented), but if you prize stability, I suggest waiting.

Comment: FYI:  Personally I'd avoid using a LTS to next-non-LTS, (ie. 20.04 to 21.10) unless you really had reason to use it. Yes it receives CI testing, and even appears on the ISO.QA testing tracker during part of the *development* cycle for QA testing, but it's not a very popular path; and gets far less attention than the every-release, or LTS-to-next-LTS upgrade paths.  Yes I've used it, and without issue, but it's still not my own personal choice (it's also something that wasn't always *supported* in Ubuntu...)

Comment: This answer is really a comment... but I was too wordy for comment thus why it's here...